# python sqlite3 code works in global space but thows error when I place it in a function

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to run the follwoing 'sqlite3_custom_type.py' example from the book "Python Standard Library by Example".  The following code works 'straight out of the box':

```
import os
import sqlite3


db_filename = 'todo.db'

db_is_new = not os.path.exists(db_filename)

conn = sqlite3.connect(db_filename)

if db_is_new:
    print('need to create schema')
else:
    print('database exists, assume schema does to')

conn.close()

#import sqlite3
try:
    import cPickle as pickle
except:
    import pickle

db_filename = 'todo.db'

def adapter_func(obj):
    """Convert from in-memory to storage representation.
    """
    print 'adapter_func(%s)\n' % obj
    return pickle.dumps(obj)

def converter_func(data):
    """Convert from storage to in-memory representation.
    """
    print 'converter_func(%r)\n' % data
    return pickle.loads(data)


class MyObj(object):
    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.arg = arg
    def __str__(self):
        return 'MyObj(%r)' % self.arg

# Register the functions for manipulating the type.
sqlite3.register_adapter(MyObj, adapter_func)
sqlite3.register_converter("MyObj", converter_func)

# Create some objects to save.  Use a list of tuples so
# the sequence can be passed directly to executemany().
to_save = [ (MyObj('this is a value to save'),),
            (MyObj(42),),
            ]

with sqlite3.connect(db_filename,
                     detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES) as conn:
    # Create a table with column of type "MyObj"
    conn.execute("""
    create table if not exists obj (
        id    integer primary key autoincrement not null,
        data  MyObj
    )
    """)
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    # Insert the objects into the database
    cursor.executemany("insert into obj (data) values (?)", to_save)

    # Query the database for the objects just saved
    cursor.execute("select id, data from obj")
    for obj_id, obj in cursor.fetchall():
        print 'Retrieved', obj_id, obj, type(obj)
        print
```

But if I put the all the code in a function such as

```
def stuff():
    ~same code as above but indented
if __name__=="__main__":
    stuff()
```

then I get an error code:

```
cursor.executemany("insert into obj (data) values (?)", to_save)
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.
```

Why doesn't the code work when it is in a function and how can I make it work?

Comment: The insert statement is in the 7th last line of the code

Comment: i use to past a class in the __main__ not a method. and it's works

Comment: the todo.db containt some tables or not yet

Comment: todo.db has no tables in it.  If I run the script in a new directory then a new todo.db is created.

Comment: try cursor.executemany("insert into to_save values (? ? ?)", to_save)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Tichodroma's answer, you need to take out *all* of the classes and functions out of the `stuff` function, including `sqlite3.register_adapter` and `sqlite3.register_converter`. Also, as a general stylistic point, [your imports should go at the top of the script](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports).

The following code works:

```
import os
import sqlite3
try:
    import cPickle as pickle
except:
    import pickle

class MyObj(object):
    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.arg = arg
    def __str__(self):
        return 'MyObj(%r)' % self.arg

def adapter_func(obj):
    """Convert from in-memory to storage representation.
    """
    print('adapter_func(%s)\n' % obj)
    return pickle.dumps(obj)

def converter_func(data):
    """Convert from storage to in-memory representation.
    """
    print('converter_func(%r)\n' % data)
    return pickle.loads(data)

# Register the functions for manipulating the type.
sqlite3.register_adapter(MyObj, adapter_func)
sqlite3.register_converter("MyObj", converter_func)

def stuff():
    db_filename = 'todo.db'

    db_is_new = not os.path.exists(db_filename)

    conn = sqlite3.connect(db_filename)

    if db_is_new:
        print('need to create schema')
    else:
        print('database exists, assume schema does to')

    conn.close()

    db_filename = 'todo.db'

    # Create some objects to save.  Use a list of tuples so
    # the sequence can be passed directly to executemany().
    to_save = [ (MyObj('this is a value to save'),),
                (MyObj(42),),
                ]

    with sqlite3.connect(db_filename,
                         detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES) as conn:
        # Create a table with column of type "MyObj"
        conn.execute("""
        create table if not exists obj (
            id    integer primary key autoincrement not null,
            data  MyObj
        )
        """)
        cursor = conn.cursor()

        # Insert the objects into the database
        cursor.executemany("insert into obj (data) values (?)", to_save)

        # Query the database for the objects just saved
        cursor.execute("select id, data from obj")
        for obj_id, obj in cursor.fetchall():
            print('Retrieved', obj_id, obj, type(obj))
            print()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    stuff()
```

Answer (score 2):

As per other answers, it's good style to place classes in module scope.  The real reason for failure in this particular case though, is because of the `pickle.dumps(obj)` call which tries to pickle a non-module level class.

Try the following code in your `adapter_func`:

```
def adapter_func(obj):
    """Convert from in-memory to storage representation.
    """
    try:
        return pickle.dumps(obj)
    except Exception, arg:
        print 'Failed to pickle object [%s]' % arg
```

You will see an error such as the following when `MyObj` is declared inside `stuff`:

```
Failed to pickle object [Can't pickle <class '__main__.MyObj'>: it's not found as __main__.MyObj]
```

It is a requirement of `pickle` that classes to be pickled are declared at the module level as [described in the pickle documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled).  The sqlite3 module appears to be squashing exceptions raised in the adapter functions, rather than propagating them through resulting in a silent failure.

You can declare and register your adapter and converter functions inside `stuff`.  Style issues aside, you could also declare your `MyObj` inside your function and have it work, as long as you find some other way to serialise/deserialise your object.

It's the attempt to pickle a class which isn't at the top level which is the root of this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Don't put the classes and functions inside of `stuff`. Especially, don't put `MyObj` inside there.

If you want to use the  `if __name__=="__main__":` condition, only put the code that is *not* a class or a function inside of `stuff`.

Comment: I took `MyObj`, `adapter_func`, and `converter_func` definitions out of `stuff` but I still get the same error in the same spot.

Comment: It does work; I needed the extra (obvious many would say) advice to put my `import pickle` before any of my function definitions.